# Configure many-to-many relationship in ASP.NET Core MVC and Entity Framework against

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, many-to-many

I am trying to configure the relationship many-to-many between two tables, `Employee` and `Project`.

One `Employee` can participate in many projects, and one project can have many `Employees` working on it. So I created two model classes `Employee` and `Project`, and I added the table `Employee_Project`.

These are my three model classes:

```
namespace WebApp2.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int Emp_Id { get; set; }
        public string Emp_Name { get; set; }
        public string Emp_Email { get; set; }
        public string Emp_Mobile { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Employee_Project> Employee_Projects { get; set; }
    }

    public class Project
    {
        [Key]
        public int Proj_Id { get; set; }
        public string Proj_Name { get; set; }
        public string Project_Details { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Employee_Project> Employee_Projects { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employee_Project
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order =1)]
        public int Emp_Id { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        public int Proj_Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I then added this `DbContext` class:

```
namespace WebApp2.Data
{
    public class MyDbContext:DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> option):base(option)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee_Project>().HasKey(pt => new { pt.Proj_Id, pt.Emp_Id });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee_Project>()
                        .HasOne(pt => pt.Employee)
                        .WithMany(pt => pt.Employee_Projects)
                        .HasForeignKey(p => p.Emp_Id);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee_Project>()
                        .HasOne(pt => pt.Project)
                        .WithMany(pt => pt.Employee_Projects)
                        .HasForeignKey(p => p.Proj_Id);
        }

        public DbSet<Employee_Project> Employee_Projects { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I created after that the three controllers

```
public class ProjectController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _context;

        public ProjectController(MyDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_context.projects.ToList());
        }

        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Project project)
        {
            _context.projects.Add(project);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }




public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _context;

        public EmployeeController(MyDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_context.Employees.ToList());
        }

        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Employee employee)
        {
             _context.Employees.Add(employee);
            _context.SaveChanges(); 
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }





public class Emp_ProjController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _DbContext;

        public Emp_ProjController(MyDbContext DbContext)
        {
            _DbContext = DbContext;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_DbContext.Employee_Projects.ToList());
        }

        
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.emp=_DbContext.Employees.ToList();
            ViewBag.pro=_DbContext.projects.ToList();
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(int empid, int [] projIds)
        {
            foreach (var item in projIds)
            {
                Employee_Project emp = new Employee_Project();
                emp.Emp_Id = empid;
                emp.Proj_Id = item;
                _DbContext.Employee_Projects.Add(emp);
                _DbContext.SaveChanges();

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
            
            
        }

    }
```

After that foreach Controllers I made the view for the method Index and Create

Emp_Proj

//view Index

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApp2.Models.Employee_Project>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Employee.Emp_Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Project.Proj_Name)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Employee.Emp_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project.Proj_Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>

//view Create

<h2>Create</h2>

<form method="post">
    <div>
        <label>Employee Name</label>
        @Html.DropDownList("empid", new SelectList(ViewBag.emp, "Emp_Id","Emp_Email"),"Select Employee")
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Select Project</label>
       @* @Html.DropDownList("proid", new SelectList(ViewBag.pro, "Proj_Id","Proj_Name"),"Select Project")*@

        <ul>
            @foreach(var item in ViewBag.pro )
            {
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="projIds" value="@item.Proj_Id">@item.Proj_Name
                </li>
            }
        </ul>

        <input  type="submit" value="SaveData"/>
        
    </div>
</form>
```

I don't have problem in the Employee and the project, I found the problem when I want to create a Emp_Proj element
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcCoB.png)
It always gives me an error like that:

SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Employee_Projects'. Cannot insert duplicate key into object 'dbo.Employee_Projects'. Duplicate key value: (1, 1).
The instruction has been terminated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaV1d.png)

Can someone please help me to find the problem? Thanks in advance.

I try to find the problem, and I appreciate some assistance.

Comment: The exception explains itself, doesn't it? You don't check if the combination already exists in the database.

Comment: Maybe, check **key order** in **modelBuilder.Entity<Employee_Project>().HasKey(pt => new { pt.Proj_Id, pt.Emp_Id });**

Comment: @ValNik, I do not inderstand the Key order

Comment: In Employee_Project: Emp_id defined column order=1, Proj_Id column order=2.  And then you use new{Proj_id,Emp_id}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message has show the reason why cause this exception: The database already contains this record, you can't insert duplicate data. You just need to check if it already exists in the database before inserting data, Please refer to this simple demo.

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(int empid, int[] projIds)
        {
            foreach (var item in projIds)
            {
                //check if the database already has this record
                var empdb = _DbContext.Employee_Projects.Where(x => x.Emp_Id == empid && x.Proj_Id == item).FirstOrDefault();

                if (empdb==null)
                {
                    Employee_Project emp = new Employee_Project();
                    emp.Emp_Id = empid;
                    emp.Proj_Id = item;
                    _DbContext.Employee_Projects.Add(emp);
                }
                
           
            }
            _DbContext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: Hello, Xinran Shen Thanks a lot, It works correctly, I can see all my recordings in the database, but I cannot see the datas in the table, the table is empty. In the Index page of Emp_ProjController, I want to  see the name of employee and the name of the project but it's empty

Comment: @user95 what do you mean by "recordings"? are you trying to seed data? how are you trying to insert data? is your problem with the table being empty? or employee and project names not being present as columns for the association table? because that's an entirely different topic.

Comment: you probably should ask a new question as your problem is gone.

Comment: when I added some Employees and projects it works but I connot sees the data in the view Index, but When I opened my table Employee_Projects in sql server i can see all the recordings.Can I send anothers pictures ?

Answer (score 0):

First off, try to remove "Employee_Project" entity entirely, and see if EF Core can auto-create it. EF Core should be able to auto-generate the association table as long as the two navigational properties are set on the two Entities. Note that navigational properties of the two entities are supposed to reference each other. like so;

in Employee;

```
public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
```

and in Project;

```
public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

In case that doesn't work, modify your Employee_Project class like this;

```
public class Employee_Project
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order =1)]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }

        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    }
```

The naming of the columns might have been the problem.